# How to get information from option field in django?

Tags: django, authentication

I have django application with authentication and I have dropdown menu inside.
Before I did it like:

```
<select name="country" id="id_category" data="{{ data.country }}">
        {% for each in living_countries_list %}
             <option name="country" value="{{ each.0 }}" class="living_countries">{{ each.1 }}</option>
        % endfor %}
</select>
```

And now I changed it to:

```
                <input list="brow" placeholder="Search for your country..." class="input_country">
                <datalist id="brow">
                    {% for each in living_countries_list %}
                        <option name="country" value="{{ each.0 }}" class="living_countries">{{ each.1 }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </datalist>
                <p class="country_text">Please select your living country</p>
```

In my views.py file I passed context like:

```
country = request.POST.get('country')

professors = models.Professor.objects.all()
living_countries_list = LIVING_COUNTRIES
print(country)
```

In models.py I have options like:

```
LIVING_COUNTRIES = [
    ('AFGANISTAN', 'Afganistan'),
    ('ALBANIA', 'Albania'),
    ('ALGERIA', 'Algeria'),
    ('ANGORRA', 'Andorra'),
    ('ANGOLA', 'Angola')]
class Professor(models.Model):
    country_living = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=LIVING_COUNTRIES, default=FRESHMAN, blank=True, null=True)
```

So I have few options which are displayed either way but in changed I can type in input and that's what I want to be able to do.

If you want me to post anything else let me know in comments

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create forms with traditional methods in django. Create first FormSet in views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import models
from django.forms import modelformset_factory

def formpageview(request):
    ProfessorFormSet = modelformset_factory(models.Professor, fields=('country_living',))
    queryset = models.Professor.objects.filter(pk=1) # you can make the filter whatever you want it doesn't have to be that way
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ProfessorFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=queryset,)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            # do something.
    else:
        formset = ProfessorFormSet(queryset=queryset,)
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'formset': formset})
```

and then use this formset in form.html:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

You should review the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template)